# using PHP foreach loop to add ID's to table columns

Tags: php

I am looking to add column IDs to a table created by a foreach loop like this.  Help is appreciated!:

```
echo "<h1>Table: {$table}</h1>";
echo "<table border='0'><tr>";

echo "</tr>\n";
// printing table rows
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
    echo "<tr>";

    // $row is array... foreach( .. ) puts every element
    // of $row to $cell variable
    foreach($row as $cell)
        echo "<td>$cell</td>";

    echo "</tr>\n";
```

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: so what is the issue in the fetching ids from table or where the ids are stored?

Comment: Right now the table has no ids.  I'd like to use a script that auto assings an id to each column of the table so I can start writing CSS and jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
echo "<tr>";

// $row is array... foreach( .. ) puts every element
// of $row to $cell variable
foreach($row as $colName=>$colValue)

// do wathever you like here

echo "</tr>\n";
```

Regards

Answer (score 1):

I quite don't understand if you need an id for each cell or row or... column ?

For row :

```
$i = 1;
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
    echo '<tr id="row-"'.$i.'">';

    // $row is array... foreach( .. ) puts every element
    // of $row to $cell variable
    foreach($row as $cell)
        echo "<td>$cell</td>";

    echo "</tr>\n";
    $i++;
}
```

For cell :

```
$i = 1;
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
    echo '<tr>';

    // $row is array... foreach( .. ) puts every element
    // of $row to $cell variable
    foreach($row as $cell)
        echo '<td id="cell-"'.$i.'">$cell</td>';

    echo "</tr>\n";
    $i++;
}
```

**Notes :**

**1-**

Why are you using this :

```
echo "<table border='0'><tr>";
echo "</tr>\n";
```

instead of : 
    `echo "<table border='0'><tr></tr>\n";`
or even better :
    `echo "<table border='0'><tr><td></td></tr>";`
Since you know you're using only one cell.

**2-**

Since you're introducing a `int` as an id (well, it's usually the case... incremental Ids) and that html's id can't start with a number, you *must* put something in front of it.

Answer (score 0):

@user547794: I'm not entirely sure what you mean, but if you just wish to assign an `id` to each cell, this should do the trick --

```
echo "<h1>Table: {$table}</h1>\n";
echo '<table cellspacing="0">' . "\n";

$i = 1;

// printing table rows
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
    echo "<tr>\n";

    // $row is array... foreach( .. ) puts every element
    // of $row to $cell variable
    foreach($row as $cell)
    {
        echo '<td id="r' . $i . '">$cell</td>' . "\n";
    }

    echo "</tr>\n";
    $i++;
}

echo "</table>\n";
```